# Powershell loop in file management

Tags: c, powershell

I have 2000 pdb files with name as `1.pdb`,`2.pdb`,`3.pdb`,`4.pdb` and so on. I have to categorize them into 3 folders according to a specific string which occurs in that files . If a file contain  a line `"REMARK 350 SOFTWARE DETERMINED QUATERNARY STRUCTURE: MONOMERIC"` so we have to move that file from given folder to a folder having a path `"E:\home\Software\"`
I think we have to use for loop from 1 to 200 , open that file and check the specific string and according to that move that file.
Though I not much familiar with power-shell, I have written my program in C. But i have found out some syntax error in that and also i m dealing with 1K pdb files, so using C is so inefficient in these case ,though i have written a code in C but i have a problem in giving a path ,syntax error is occurring in every case . 
Can anyone help me in both cases ?

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #define MAX 1024
  #include <stdarg.h>
  main()
 {    
     FILE *fp;
     char line[MAX];
     char var[MAX];
     int j=0;
     char i;


     char inputpath[20]= ("E:/Project/imp/1");
     strcat(inputpath,".pdb");
     fp=fopen(inputpath,"r");
     int num;
     while(i<"EOF")
     {
         fscanf(fp,"%s",var);
         if(strcmp(var,"AUTHOR")==0)
        {
                j++;
               break;

        }
      }
     fclose(fp);

        if (j==1)

        {

           // printf("efg\n");


            system("move E:\\Project\\imp\\1.pdb d:\\" );
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to find a solution yourself? If so, post the code & describe where you get stuck.

Comment: I you haven't attempted to find a solution take a look at the Switch loop, give it a try, and let us know if you still need help, and what errors you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

This Powershell 2.0+ code (with proper paths replaced) should do what you want:

```
$baseFolderPath = 'C:\SourceFolderPath'
$targetFolderPath = 'C:\TargetFolderPath'
$findStr = 'REMARK 350 SOFTWARE DETERMINED QUATERNARY STRUCTURE: MONOMERIC'

# Get the list of .pdb files
$pdbList = Get-ChildItem -Path $baseFolderPath -Filter '*.pdb'

foreach( $pdb in $pdbList )
{
    # Make sure path is no folder
    if( Test-Path -Path $pdb.FullName -PathType Leaf )
    {
        $pdbLines = Get-Content -Path $pdb.FullName
        foreach( $line in $pdbLines )
        {
            # Check if line matches
            if( $line -like $findStr )
            {
                # Move file to target folder
                Move-Item -Path $pdb.FullName -Destination $targetFolderPath
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```